# How to limit the number of records returned by BAPI call using JCO3

Tags: saprfc, bapi, sapjco3

When retrieving information from SAP system, in certain cases, we get results in hundreds or thousands. In such cases, if we want to implement a kind of pagination mechanism, what are the options available in JCO3.

First of all, how to restrict the records to a desired number (100 or 1000, etc)? Where should we define this?

How to continue to the next iteration of results with a limited records in each iteration/page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the  BAPI / function module you're using. If the BAPI supports pagination, fine - if it doesn't, the JCo won't be able to help you out. You'll have to retrieve all records and do the pagination in your application.

Comment: Oh, that is interesting!! But if the number of records are too huge, doesn't the application go out of memory? How can we manage this? Any helpful attributes to work with like buffer, etc....on which class? Thanks

Comment: If you ask the system for all materials/postings/movements/whatever, you will get all of them - or kill some application trying. Just limit your query accordingly. You should be able to do so easily - if not, check your requirements.